# Disable block caching

Tags: 8, blocks, caching

I just made a simlple block by using block > custom block, so I didn't make it programmatically.

I am a Drupal 8 newbie, and I look for a simple and clear solution how to disable caching for that block.

What code should I use ? In what file to put the code ? How to target that unique block ?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable Twig and block cache for a specific module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185215/how-do-i-disable-twig-and-block-cache-for-a-specific-module)

Comment: For custom blocks added in UI there is no known caching issue. Please add the details what is different in your case.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a custom module let's suppose it called `custom_module`, your `custom_module.module` implement `hook_preprocess_HOOK`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for block.html.twig.
 */
function custom_module_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  //- Change the block-id-name by your block id
  if($vars['derivative_plugin_id'] == 'block-id-name') {
    //- This stops the block being cache in drupal 8
    $vars['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;

  }
```

**Edit** :
if you don't know the exact `block id` you can install [Block Content Machine Name](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_content_machine_name) module, it will give you the possibility to give a machine name to your custom block, and then implement the hook like the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for block.html.twig.
 */
function custom_module_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  //- Change the block-machine-name by your block machine name
  if (isset($vars['elements']['content']['#block_content']) &&
    $vars['elements']['content']['#block_content']->get('machine_name')->value == 'block-machine-name'
  ) {
    $vars['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: to complete @berramou's answer : you can do it in theme as well as explained in following answer : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/253372/6884

Comment: Thank you much, it helped a lot