# PHP not Updating for Anonymous Users

Tags: 8

I have been running a personal dashboard on Drupal 7 for years (currently on 7.69). I rendered the dashboard in Homebox and some of the blocks use PHP (using PHP Filter) to get stock quotes, weather updates, etc.

I recently rebuilt the site in Drupal 8.8.1. I use Panels for the dashboard blocks since there is no Homebox for Drupal 8. I also added the PHP Filter module for my PHP blocks. I'll eventually put my PHP code in modules, but I'm going with PHP Filter for now. I'm using the included Bootstrap theme and caching is set to 'no caching'.

My problem is, everything runs fine when I am logged in as administrator -- the PHP code in the blocks executes every time I do a page refresh. However, when I am not logged in and I do a page refresh as an anonymous user, the PHP blocks do not update. In Drupal 7.69 the page will update for an anonymous user, which is the behavior I want. I've compared permissions between the two installations and everything looks the same. I must be missing something here.

Has anyone else used PHP Filter with Drupal 8 and run into this?

Comment: Caching is radically different in Drupal 8. By default it will cache all pages for anon users. Unless your site has very little traffic this is usually a good idea. You can turn off caching (see eg https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-turn-off-drupal-8-caching) but performance will suffer.

Comment: You should definitely refactor these scripts to be provided via custom Drupal blocks from a custom module and then disable block caching from there. Since I think the PHP Filter module exposes a big security risk for any site. Until then you can disable the caching for the blocks with a couple lines of code yourself. Google for Drupal 8 programmatically disable block cache.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable block caching](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271834/disable-block-caching)

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong – OP should turn off caching just for these blocks not for the entire site.

Comment: @leymannx you are right of course. I started thinking about how to do this more optimally and then realised how long the answer might be, and gave up and posted this comment instead without thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of the PHP filter:

```
class Php extends FilterBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function process($text, $langcode) {
    $result = new FilterProcessResult(php_eval($text));
    $result->setCacheMaxAge(0);
    return $result;
  }
```

https://git.drupalcode.org/project/php/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Plugin/Filter/Php.php

it sets already a cache max age of 0, so you only need to remove the page cache for anonymous users by uninstalling the module "Internal Page Cache".

Comment: Thanks -- I had already tried this. When I uninstalled 'Internal Page Cache' it killed my blocks entirely, no content displays in the PHP blocks at all for any user -- even after reinstalling that module.

Comment: Wouldn't it be fine then to just disable cache of these certain blocks? Why the whole page?

Comment: Yes, disabling the caching on the specific blocks makes the most sense. I'm still very new at Drupal 8. I'll try your above 'Disable block caching' suggestion after I've restored the blocks to their original functionality. Thanks.

Comment: @leymannx, Internal Page Cache has only one use case, serving static database content to anonymous users. If all or most pages contain blocks changing for each request the module doesn't work and you have to use the Dynamic Page Cache, which can placeholder and lazy-load such dynamic blocks.

Comment: @RichardD, you don't have to disable caching for specific blocks because the text filter does this already by bubbling up a cache max age of 0.

Comment: @4k4 – Are you on drupal.org? I should definitely list you as my mentor.

Comment: @4k4, thanks, it's working now. Disabling the 'Internal Page Cache' module does exactly what I want. It turns out that disabling 'Internal Page Cache' turned off 'PHP Filter' for some reason. After reinstalling 'PHP Filter', there is no caching for anonymous users. Yay! And yes, my next step is to create custom modules and get rid of 'PHP Filter', but for now, all is good.