# How to un-cache a specific node field (also for anonymous)

Tags: 8, nodes, caching

My goal is to replace (by a custom markup) the render array of `field_product` when some conditions are met. (in a ecommerce site)

**Ex:** If this is the weekend or if it is after 12pm the `field_product` must not be rendered (but a markup like "the webshop is closed")

In `mymodule_preprocess_node(&$vars)` I have tried without success:

```
$vars['content']['field_product']['#cache']['max-age']=0;
```

or

```
$vars['content']['field_product']['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'session';
```

Unfortunately, it is not working for anonymous users

The only solution I found is:

```
$vars['#cache']['max-age']=0;
```

But as you can see, all the node is un-cached... not the `field_product`

What is wrong with my code?

Again: this should be uncached for anonymous users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure you add `#cache` data inside of a render array only to render elements (containing `#type`, `#theme` or `#markup`). In other places of a render array it doesn't work.

Where you add cache max-age or contexts inside of an entity doesn't make a difference though, because there is no field level, only entity level caching.

Another problem is page caching for anonymous users. See [How do I disable Twig and block cache for a specific module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185215/how-do-i-disable-twig-and-block-cache-for-a-specific-module)

Comment: Thank you, I understand that it is not feasible... I have to invalidate all the node. Thank you!