# Excerpt of Search API index is cached

Tags: 8, search, caching

I'm using the search_api extension (V 8.x-1.14) with the Database search (no solr, etc.)

I use the search block which is created by the search view (`/search` path)

I want to show the highlighted excerpts which are setup in the *Manage processors for search index*  (`/admin/config/search/search-api/<x>/content/processors`)

In the view I select *Rendered Entity* as show format and chose *search result hightlighing input* in the settings.

Everything works fine now, but ...

Consifer I have a page *About us* with this sentence written somewhere on the page.

> 'We will deliver your quality product on time and safely at the location of your choice.'

When the user searches for `time`, this page will be hit and the correct highlight will be shown

> We will deliver your quality product on **time** and safely at the location of your choice.

Now this excerpt is cached and when I search for *quality* the excerpt stays the same with the wrong word highlighted.

> We will deliver your quality product on **time** and safely at the location of your choice.

I deactivated the cache of the view, but it didn't change anything

Comment: Did you tried to set cache `max-age` to 0 for search block see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185215/how-do-i-disable-twig-and-block-cache-for-a-specific-module

Comment: @berramou Thank's a lot. That hinted me in the right direction

Comment: Good, i'm glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [berramou](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/84694/berramou)!

I ended up using this in my theme:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(array &$variables) {
  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'search_result') {
    $variables['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
  }
}
```