# Cache Exclude functionality in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, caching

How can I prevent a specific node - or a list of specific nodes - being cached server-side in Drupal 8?

I have page that pulls a value out of a $_SESSION variable using a PHP text block, and it is being cached, which is obviously not what I want.

Comment: A php text block evaluates only the output, no cache data. So you probably need to add the cache data somewhere else, for example in a node preprocess or view alter hook. But then you can place the rest of the php code there as well.

Comment: See also some of the related questions like http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/151254/how-can-i-prevent-a-particular-page-being-cached?rq=1 which answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by doing the following:

- I appended a cache buster querystring parameter to the link to the page that needed to be kept out of cache (using the timestamp token + random number token)
- Added the `'url.query_args'` cache context to the `required_cache_contexts` in services.yml

It puts a bit more strain on the memory use of the cache than just keeping it out of cache altogether, but the `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();` line did not do anything for me at all.

I think it makes sense for the querystring to be part of the default cache context anyway.